# Getting Bing Maps Elevation Data Through Webservice and FilterXML produces VALUE Error

Tags: excel, bing-maps, excel-365

This is in Excel 365.

I have a valid Bing Maps API key and have used similar formulas to get latitude and longitude data for addresses in spreadsheets.

Trying to do the same thing with elevation data doesn't want to work, however, and after consulting Bing's documentation and searching online, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/List?points={"&I1092&","&J1092&"}&key={"&BingKey&"}"),"//*")
```

BingKey is a named range containing the key, and columns I and J hold latitude and longitude values. I've tried replacing all references with literal values, but I still get an error. The Xpath is purposely set to return everything just to see if I can get the webservice part of the formula to work.

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.

1. You have curly braces around the lati/lon and key values, when concatenated, these are being added to the string, making those values invalid.
2. The default response format is JSON and you are trying to parse it as XML, thus the error message in Excel that the format is incorrect. Add `&output=xml` to the URL and it works.

Here is a modified version of the formula you provided.

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/List?points="&I1092&","&J1092&"&output=xml&key="&BingKey),"//*")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.

I tied your edit, but I'm still getting a value error.

Also, the brackets were part of the sample code in Bing's API documentation. (But not in other requests, so I assumed they were relevant).

The output = xml part was also not necessary for other requests like lat/long or traveltime to work.

Comment: That formula creates multiple lines of cells with the first cell being "#VALUE", but further down the information is extracted. I've added a screen shot to my original response. As for having to set the format to XML, the elevation service came out many years after the other Bing Maps services when JSON had become the main default for cloud services.

Comment: Here is a modified version of the formula that gets the first elevation value. Note I have different lat/lon/key cell index values as per the test file I was using, so you will need to update those:

`=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/List?points="&A4&","&B4&"&output=xml&key="&B1),"//int")`

Comment: Okay, so I see this and your original solution work for you, and it also works for me in a new workbook. But it still doesn't work in my existing workbook that I was working on.

Is it possible that this, along with some other filterxml funkiness (random value errors in some rows, that clear up when clicking into the cell) is because the workbook was created in Excel 2013? The funkiness started happening with the switch to Excel365 (I miss 2013...). I have a separate, older topic open about @filterxml being unreliable since then.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the filterxml formula in Excel so can't really provide any insights there. Your original formula looks to be using a keyword for the Bing Maps key, so make sure that is working correctly. As a test, I would concatenate the URL string in another cell, to verify it looks correct (you can also copy/paste it into a browser to make sure it works). This helped me debug the original issue.